# ASP.NET Form View problem please have a glance

Tags: asp.net

Hello friends i have a form view
i have handele all needed events successfully but for cancel(not to insert or update) i have done the following

> protected void companyForm_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
>       {
>           if (e.CommandName == "Cancel")
>           {
>               companyForm.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);
>           }
>       }

But i have to twice click the button to change it in default or in read only  mode please explain me y....or some other way exist to for "cancel" command

Comment: Please have a glance ...i am in dire need...

Comment: Next time you're in dire need, tag your questions properly. That way they might actually get answered :)

Comment: skaffman  i am resolved with this but with some unusual alternate way
but i want to go to actual reason ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that you forgot to call the DataBind() method, try this:

```
    protected void companyForm_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e) 
    {
         if (e.CommandName == "Cancel")
         { 
             companyForm.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);
             companyForm.DataSource= <THE SOURCE> ;
             companyForm.DataBind();
         }
    }
```

Comment: YES u r true but y it chnge mode when i do twice click the button...
and when i have mentioned it to change mode using
companyForm.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
y do externally need to bind it with data source ....same happens in edit mode we have to bind it externally

Comment: that's beacause the first time you click you change the mode but you don't bind the source, when you click again, the DataBind() you put in one of the page loading events is called, the formview goes in ReadOnly mode (according to the previous postback) and then again the companyForm_ItemCommand sets the formview mode to readonly (no change is made actually)

Comment: astorcas thnks sir for your answer, i got it now